# Git Refreshing Index Error (Aptana Studio 3)

Tags: git, refresh, aptana3, git-index

I have been having the problem below for the last couple of days. I am fairly new to git, so I am not sure what is causing this problem.

I do not know where to go from here.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Refreshing Git Index Error]

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message, you're trying to perform an operation in a directory which isn't in a git repository.

Try running it from e.g. the root of your repo (the one with the `.git` directory)

Comment: I think the problem may have been:

When I imported a directory of as a new project, it was the parent directory of the git repository. I deleted that project, and just imported the git repository as the project. I have not run into the same error yet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you initiliaze a Git repo in the directory?

Do so by typing "git init" in Git bash.